# cartCookieDuration and purgeInactiveCartsDuration config settings

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

How do I set the cartCookieDuration and purgeInactiveCartsDuration for only 24 hours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to the Commerce documentation for each (https://craftcommerce.com/docs/configuration#cartcookieduration and https://craftcommerce.com/docs/configuration#purgeinactivecartsduration), they both link to the PHP [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php) class page that describes the various time formats you can use.

For 24 hours, either `P24H` or `P1D` should do it.